# Let $T$ be a stopping time. Is $M_T$ well-defined in this exercise?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

I'm doing an exercise about martingale and stopping time:

> [image]

To remove ambiguity, I include how my lecture note define a random walk:

> Let $(X_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be an i.i.d sequence of random variables in which $\mathbb P(X_1 = 1)=p$ and $\mathbb P(X_1 = -1)=1-p$. We define a sequence $(S_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ of random variables by $S_0 = s \in \mathbb R$ and $S_{n} = S_0+ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then $(S_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is called a random walk.

---

In my understanding, for $M_T$ and $S_T$ to be well-defined, $T$ must be finite stopping time. However, it seems to me that there is no guarantee the set $\{n \in \mathbb N \mid S_n \in \{a,b\}\}$ is non-empty.

Could you please elaborate on my confusion? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well known that for $p \neq \frac 1  2 $  the random walk is transient $|S_n| \to \infty$ with probability $1$. Hence if $S_0 \in (a,b)$ it is guaranteed that $S_n\in \{a,b\}$ for some finite $n$ with probability $1$.

Comment: Could you please explain more on how to go from $|S_n| \to \infty$ to $S_n\in \{a,b\}$?

Comment: @Navier_Stokes The random walk moves only one step at  a time. It cannot go out of $(a,b)$ without touching either $a$ or $b$.

Comment: But we are not given $S_0 \in \mathbb Z$. It's just $S_0 \in (a,b)$.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry :(. In my lecture $S_0 = s \in \mathbb Z$, not $S_0 = s \in \mathbb R$. Your answer is perfectly fine. I would like to ask one more question: To solve $\mathbb E(M_T) = \mathbb E(M_0)$ in question (b), so we need to assume $(M_n)$ is a martingale?